# Load Runner scripting, Scenario based query

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to ask question on one scenario of loadrunner scripting, there is one e-commerce site and we need to purchase a t-shirt of different color, we have recorded the script but while replaying we need to modify a script in such a way that user should select a t-shirt randomly and depend on t-shirt it should pick a random color as well, how to implement this logic in load runner script. Kindly help me to know logic of it.

Comment: Read about parametrization in the product documentation.  http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/114150_c_parameter_types.htm

Comment: Please post your relevant request. In it is an ID or string, we can randomly generate using `Parameterization` or programmatically. Thanks!